# Secant method in matlab stops before it reaches the epsilon

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

So I'm pretty new to MATLAB and numerical analysis and I'm trying to write the code for the secant method, but for some reason it just stops after the first iteration.
Here is my code for the secant method:

```
function [root] = secant(func, x0, x1, N, eps_step, max_eps)
    last_x = x0;
    curr_x = x1;
    new_x = x1;
    diff_x = curr_x - last_x;
    diff_f = func(curr_x) - func(last_x);
    k = 0;

    if func(x0) == 0
        root = x0;
        fprintf('results for secant iterations \n');
        fprintf('                         x0,x1                k          x_k       f(x_k)       |x_k-x_(k+1)|\n')
        fprintf('                  ---------------            ---      -----------  ---------  ---------------\n')
        fprintf('N = %12.8f {x0=%12.8f,x1=%12.8f} %3i    %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f \neps = %3i \ndelta = %3i \n\n',N, last_x, curr_x, k ,last_x,func(new_x), diff_x, eps_step, max_eps)
        return;
    elseif func(x1) == 0
        root = x1;
        fprintf('results for secant iterations \n');
        fprintf('                         x0,x1                  k          x_k       f(x_k)       |x_k-x_(k+1)|\n')
        fprintf('                  ---------------              ---      -----------  ---------  ---------------\n')
        fprintf('N = %12.8f {x0=%12.8f,x1=%12.8f} %3i    %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f \neps = %3i \ndelta = %3i \n\n',N, last_x, curr_x, k ,curr_x,func(new_x), diff_x, eps_step, max_eps)
        return;
    end

    while (k < N) 
       k = k+1;
       diff_x = curr_x - last_x;
       diff_f = func(curr_x) - func(last_x);
       new_x = curr_x - func(curr_x)*(diff_x/diff_f);   % compute the new value of x
       % if abs((new_x - curr_x)*(diff_f/diff_x)+func(curr_x)) < max_eps
       fprintf('eps_step = %12.8f\n', eps_step); %Doesnt print this line for some reason
       if (abs(diff_x) < eps_step)
           if (abs(diff_f) < max_eps && new_x > 0)
                root = new_x;
                fprintf('results for secant iterations \n');
                fprintf('                         x0,x1                       k          x_k       f(x_k)       |x_k-x_(k+1)|\n')
                fprintf('                    ---------------                 ---      -----------  ---------  ---------------\n')
                fprintf('N = %12.8f {x0=%12.8f,x1=%12.8f} %3i    %12.8f %12.8f %12.8f \neps = %3i \ndelta = %3i \n\n',N, x0, x1, k ,new_x,func(new_x), diff_x, eps_step, max_eps)
                break
            end
            
       end
       last_x = curr_x;
       curr_x = new_x;
       
    end
end
```

the function and call function are:

```
func = @(x) x.^2-0.2-4*x.*sin(x)+(2*sin(x)).^2;
secant(func, 0, 1, 50, 10^-6, 10^-6);
```

But the result I get is:

```
results for secant iterations 
                         x0,x1                       k          x_k       f(x_k)       |x_k-x_(k+1)|
                    ---------------                 ---      -----------  ---------  ---------------
N =  50.00000000 {x0=  0.00000000,x1=  1.00000000}   1      0.42880752  -0.03777984   1.00000000 
eps = 1.000000e-06 
delta = 1.000000e-06
```

the root is supposed to be 0.484736. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Is Matlab at this level different from octave? I thought them compatible. Code copied directly results in the output line`N =  50.00000000 {x0=  0.00000000,x1=  1.00000000}   6      0.48473602  -0.00000000   0.00000093`. Could you run your code again in a fresh work space?  /// Hard comparisons to zero in numerical codes are useless. Compare against an error level. The initial assignment of `curr_x, last_x` is not used before the loop and immediately repeated inside the loop. Repeated code like the reporting lines should be centralized in an extra function or occur once via code restructuring.

Comment: @LutzLehmann seems like I do have a problem, like the code isn't running as it should. I tried saving again, restarting and changing things but it is stuck on the previous result.